# Stripping Illegal Characters from message Stream in Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have experienced an issue where there was an illegal character in a source system which when it hit the DataWeave transformer threw an error.  We have since fixed the data in the source system, however we should be able to strip this illegal character in Mule.  Here is the error that occurred when it hit the DataWeave Transformer.  I need help in how to and where to strip these "Illegal" characters.

```
ERROR 2015-11-30 17:46:16,837 [[ServiceNow].HTTP_8081_listener.worker.01] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 25))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,916] (com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
Payload               : com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler@692ffd69
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 25))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,916] (com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException)
  com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner:674 (null)
2. Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 25))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,916] (com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
********************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

The flow is expecting a valid SOAP message. If the message is invalid then what you did is the correct solution: fix the source system. Just removing characters doesn't mean the message will make sense.

Comment: unfortunately no, the message was valid however there is an illegal ascii character in one of the properties.

Comment: The XML standard specifies how to encode characters. If the message doesn't comply with the standard it is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Created Custom class to strip the illegal characters from the message.